# Using jQuery to change image source URL

Tags: jquery

I have two images, one transparent:

```
http://www.example.com/image-trans.png
```

And another one with a background:

```
http://www.example.com/image.png
```

I am trying to use jQuery to change the src of the image from `image-trans.png` (original value) to `image.png` when a certain event is triggered.

I am able to accomplish this by typing the src directly into my jQuery code:

```
$("img.nav51").attr("src","http://example.com/image.png");
```

However, I am trying to do this without typing the URL directly into my jQuery, as the URL is dynamically set elsewhere, and is subject to change.

Here is what I am trying, but it does not do anything for me:

```
$('img.nav51').attr("src").replace("-trans.png", ".png");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Replace doesn't modify the string you are "replacing." Rather it returns a new string which you must then set as the new src attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set/update the attribute you must pass the new value in the second parameter.

Try this :

```
var originalSrc = $('img.nav51').attr("src");
$('img.nav51').attr("src", originalSrc.replace("-trans.png", ".png"));
```

Comment: Or he could just use `this.src = this.src.replace("-trans.png", ".png");` I'm all for all jQuery, but sometimes, the simplest solution is Vanilla. That is, if `this` is in a click event of the image

Comment: Depending of his needs, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it to replace it:

```
$('img.nav51').attr("src", $('img.nav51').attr("src").replace("-trans.png", ".png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img.nav51').attr('src', function(){ 
     return this.src.replace("-trans.png", ".png"); 
});
```